# Disable WooCommerce shop page completely, but keep search page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with WooCommerce. I want to disable the shop page completely, but I still want users to be able to search for products.

This is what I have now - it works, but it also disables the search page, as this uses the shop page.

```
function woocommerce_disable_shop_page() {
    global $post;
    if (is_shop()):
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'woocommerce_disable_shop_page' );
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just modified code in your question & it is working. Please add below code in theme's `functions.php` file or custom plugin file.

```
function woocommerce_disable_shop_page() {
    global $post;
    if (is_shop() && !(is_search())):
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'woocommerce_disable_shop_page' );
```

Comment: Worked perfectly here. Thanks :-)